# Why can't the set difference function compare lists with data from files?

Tags: comparison, format, lisp, common-lisp, set-difference

Here are my files and functions:

List1.txt => cat 
             dog 
             tiger 
             bear

List2.txt => cat 
             dog 
             tiger

These files are ANSI encoded on winodws xp.

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
  (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
  while line collect line)))

(defparameter *file1* (get-file "list1.txt"))
(defparameter *file2* (get-file "list2.txt"))

(set-difference *file1* *file2*)
```

I would think the output would be just "bear". However, it returns ("cat", "dog", "tiger", "bear") as the difference. I am assuming it has to due with me reading the information in from files but I was stuck there. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common Lisp uses `EQL` as default test. You want `string-equal` or similar.

```
CL-USER > (set-difference '("cat" "dog" "tiger" "bear")
                          '("cat" "dog" "tiger")
                          :test #'string-equal)
->
("bear")
```

Comment: Thank you I had tried the test command but used ":test #'equal" instead of "string-equal". Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `:test` keyword parameter of [`set-difference`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_di.htm) which Rainer already mentioned, there is another problem in your code. Your function `get-file` returns a list of lines, where each line is just one string. You probably want to split the lines into words. You can do it easily with `split-sequence` function (google for the `split-sequence` Common Lisp package or get it with

```
(ql:quickload :split-sequence)
```

if you have [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) installed. So, your function could look like, for example:

```
(defun get-file (path)
  (with-open-file (s path)
    (let* ((len (file-length s))
           (data (make-string len)))
      (read-sequence data s)
      (mapcar #'(lambda (string) (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab #\Newline) string))
        (split-sequence:split-sequence '#\Space data :remove-empty-subseqs t)))))


(defparameter *file1* (get-file "list1.txt"))
(defparameter *file2* (get-file "list2.txt"))

(format t "~s~%" (set-difference *file1* *file2* :test #'string-equal))
```

This will, correctly, print:

```
("bear")
```

Comment: Thank you that is interesting. I was doing one word per line but this will allow me to do what I wanted originally.

Comment: No problem. You may actually be better off using `cl-ppcre` and `(split "\\s+" data)` instead of `split-sequence`.